# PyQt6 QTableWidgetItem Change Background Color if Value Changes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

After creating a custom QLabel class that opens a QInputDiaglog popup when double clicked to change the value displayed in the cell, I realized that a QTableWidgetItem can be double clicked to edit its value. I prefer this over the popup from a user perspective. I need to add a new property "init_val" and override a method (not sure which one, maybe write()) to change the background color and insert an entry into the changes_dict property of the main window when the edit is completed.

I looked through the documentation and used "help(QTableWidgetItem)" in console, but still could not figure it out. How can I figure this out on my own in the future?

You can ignore most of the code since it causes a lot of errors. I just wanted to give it a shot before asking for help.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHeaderView, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QLabel, QMainWindow, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QDialogButtonBox, QDialog

from PyQt6 import QtCore import sys

class MyQTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text)

        self.init_val = text
        
    def write(self, out: QtCore.QDataStream) -> None:
        print(out, type(out))
        return super().write(out)


    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        print('twas double clicked')
        self.clicked.emit()


class Window(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.column_names = ['1', '2', '3']
        self.load_table()

        self.btn = QPushButton('Insert Row')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.onClickMe())

        self.show()

    def load_table(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'table'):
            self.table = QTableWidget()
            self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

        data = [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [3, 3, 3]
        ]

        rows = len(data)
        cols = len(data[0])
        self.table.setRowCount(rows)
        self.table.setColumnCount(cols)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.column_names)

        for i, lis in enumerate(data):
            for j, item in enumerate(lis):
                print(i, lis, j, item)
                item_widget = MyQTableWidgetItem(str(item))
                self.table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(item))) 

                item_widget.clicked.connect(lambda item_widget=item_widget: self.on_double_click(item_widget, i, j))
    
    def on_double_click(self, item_widget, r, c):
        # previously I called a QInputDialog in this function, which automatically returned the text and 
        # True if the Ok button was clicked. I checked new text vs item_widget.init_val and if they were 
        # different changed background color and added change to self.changes_dict.
        # 
        # I don't know how I would pull the new text once the QTableWidgetItem value is changed.
        text = ...
        key = ...
        self.changes_dict[key] = text
        ...

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With this code I get the following error:

> File
> "C:\Users\ngreen\Desktop\Projects\wip_inv_adjustment_app\testing_qtablewidgetitem.py",
> line 65, in load_table
> item_widget.clicked.connect(lambda item_widget=item_widget: self.on_double_click(item_widget, i, j)) TypeError: MyQTableWidgetItem
> cannot be converted to PyQt6.QtCore.QObject

Previously I used `self.table.setCellWidget()` with a custom class inheriting QLabel instead of `self.table.setItem()` with a custom class inheriting QTableWidget, so this may be part of the problem.

Using @musicmante's suggestion I tried to override setData() as follows:

```
def setData(self, role: int, value: typing.Any) -> None:
    if value != self.init_val:
        self.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(127,255,212))
    else:
        self.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))

    return super().setData(role, value)
```

but got the following error. Perhaps I cannot change background color in the middle of the setData method?

> Error in sys.excepthook:
>
> Original exception was: Unhandled Python exception

Comment: Override [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData).  Also, table widget items are not QObjects, so they don't support signals, if you need to call a function when an item is changed, connect to the table's `itemChanged` signal. Finally, items are not even widgets, so the `mouseDoubleClickEvent()` function is useless.

Comment: Thanks. That explains why switching from an inheriting QLabel to an inheriting QTableWidgetItem caused so many issues.

Comment: @musicamante I tried overriding setData(), but got an error. I added more above.

Comment: `setBackground()` calls `setData()`, and you must always check for the role anyway. Add `if role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):` before checking the value and setting anything, otherwise you'll get recursion. Also take your time to read more about [Qt model/view programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) in order to understand these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Using the table's itemChanged signal as @musicamante suggested I got it to work. This is so much easier than the way I tried before.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHeaderView, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QLabel, QMainWindow, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QDialogButtonBox, QDialog
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import typing


class MyQTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.init_val = text


class Window(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.column_names = ['1', '2', '3']
        self.load_table()

        self.show()

    def load_table(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'table'):
            self.table = QTableWidget()
            self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

        data = [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [2, 2, 2],
            [3, 3, 3]
        ]

        rows = len(data)
        cols = len(data[0])
        self.table.setRowCount(rows)
        self.table.setColumnCount(cols)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.column_names)

        for i, lis in enumerate(data):
            for j, item in enumerate(lis):
                print(i, lis, j, item)
                item_widget = MyQTableWidgetItem(str(item))
                self.table.setItem(i, j, MyQTableWidgetItem(str(item))) 

        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.change_background)

    def change_background(self, item):
        if item.text != item.init_val:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(127,255,212))
        else:
            item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Simple and easy